# Division using double java

Tags: java

Im running in to this weird problem when I divide doubles in java.

System.out.println((0.39281 + 0.39281 + 0.39281)/ 3.0);

which gives me
0.39281000000000005

I was expecting obviously 0.39281 as the answer but in reality its giving me this trailing remainder too. I am just really confused as to why this is so because when i run
System.out.println((0.39281 + 0.39281)/ 2.0), i get what i expected.

What would be a good work around for this, assuming i want to store accurate values, not necessarily printing them

Thanks guys

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact.  It is a fundamental fact.  Independent of the  programming language you are using.

Comment: If you want more accuracy, use `BigDecimal`.  But be aware that even `BigDecimal` cannot store all numbers with 100% accuracy.  It is a property of the underlying mathematics.  (For example, you cannot express 1/3 as a decimal number without using an *infinite* number of 3's.)